# ASP.NET Core - can't attach to w3wp

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, w3wp

I'm using "development-time IIS support" and trying to attach w3wp for debuging. But I'm getting this warning:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

What I'm doing wrong?
IIS configured as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

iis 10 / asp.net core 2.1

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my problem solved.

In ASP.NET Core we need to attach to **dotnet.exe**. 
IIS just a shell.